# getline(file, text) exhibits strange behavior : stuck reading a ghost line

Tags: c++, file, getline

I am stuck with the strange behavior that getline is exhibiting in the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string password = "cat";
    string inputFileName = "text.txt";
    string content = ""; 

    ifstream file;
    file.open(inputFileName);
    
    if(file.fail()) {
        cout << "error opening the file" << endl;
    }
    getline(file, content);

    file.close();
    cout << "The content of the file is: " << content << endl;
}
```

The content of the file `text.txt` was originally a single line: `"This is a generic text to be encrypted"`, which was correctly copied into the string `content`.

Whenever I change the text in the file or delete its content, save it, and run the program again, the same old string is always copied to the text string variable. Even  stranger is that even deleting the file, does not throw any error, the erased file stills gets opened and `getline(file, text)` still assigns the same string to text, as shown with the debugger and by the print statement.

**What is going on here?**

This is supposed to be a simple learning exercise. If it helps I am using qtcreator on Windows 10, the Cmake file given to me has the following content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(encryption LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(encryption main.cpp)
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/text.txt
     DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

Comment: You have several files text.txt, right?

Comment: I suspect you're actually opening a different file. Search for any other files called `text.txt`. For example, in the root of the project and in either of build directories (you probably have one for Debug and one for Release, and they're distinct).

Comment: @ S.M. No, just one

Comment: @J.C.VegaO How come? You explicitly do some file copying in `CMakeLists.txt`. There have to be at least two files somewhere.

Comment: You are right there was another copy of the file in the compiled debug directory. I just don't see why

Comment: " I just don't see why " Maybe because the cmake file that you showed explicitly instructs to copy it there?

Comment: `file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/text.txt DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})` does the copy when you configure your project using CMake.

Comment: I see, thank you. I don't know anything aboutCmake, but if I admit I didn't pay attention to that line.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `ifstream file; file.open(inputFileName);` to `ifstream file(inputFileName);`. Also, you don’t need to call `file.close()`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: Without testing `getline(file, content);` for success, how do you know whether or not you got a valid line at all?

Comment: @Pete Becker  Thanks for the piece of advice. The reason I wrote them separately was for clarity. What is the downside? About the file.close(), I was told that I should always close a file. So is this a feature of C++ as compared to C? In C I do need to close it, right?

Comment: @user4581301, how can I do that?

Comment: `if (getline(file, content)) { std::cout << "We got one!"; } else { std::cout << "no line."; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, your program is not running from the directory you think it is.

Visual Studio is particularly bad about this, I find. You'll need to go into the Properties for the project and see where the current directory is set to. Either that or run it from a terminal yourself.

Edit every copy of that text file that you can find and make each one unique, then you will see which one is being used.

Also important is to know that CMake only runs those file copy operations ONE TIME, when cmake is executed. Not every time you build the project. You can arrange to do that, but it would be a custom target, not a file(COPY) operation.

Comment: I also tried re-running cmake several times with the content of text.txt changed, but that didn't updated the copied file in the debug directory which is the one being used, is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the duplicate file problem, another obvious issue is that just outputing the message:

```
 cout << "error opening the file" << endl;
```

Doesn't make the program not execute the following lines, you need to stop the rest of the code handling the file from being executed if the file is not correctly opened.

Example:

```
if (file.fail()) // IMO prefer if(!file.is_open())
{
    cout << "error opening the file" << endl;
}
else
{
    getline(file, content);
    file.close();
    cout << "The content of the file is: " << content << endl;
}
```